Is there a way to create a views block for layout builder where the admin filters the information to be show to the end user?
I have a views block where the views exposed filters is available to the end user. However, I need to allow the content editor to make the selection in the block (to be placed in layout builder) as to what to show to the end user and not let the end user decide, ie., I don't want the exposed filters exposed to the end user, just the content editor.
The reason is that this same data is used in different parts of the site, and we only want that part that pertains to show, not all of the info.
Can this be done?

Users with permission to access the view will also have permission to modify the exposed filters (that's why they are "exposed"-- exposed to the user accessing the view), so no, you cannot use exposed filters as you are hoping.
Instead, you can use a regular Filter (not an exposed filter) and let the content editor modify that filter.  However, for each combination of filters, you will need to clone the block and place the clone where it needs to be. (If you let multiple content editors edit the same block, their changes will overwrite each other.)
If there are really a lot of these, I would try to find a way to use a Contextual Filter instead, which allows the developer to set the arguments for the View filters from, for example, the URL.
